# Groovy execute external RTC command with quotes in the command

Tags: groovy, rtc

I have an external command I am trying to run from Groovy.  The command has quotes embedded in the command and I'm getting the following error:

```
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.String.waitFor() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
```

I have tried escaping the quotes with backslashes, but that does not work either.

Here is an example of the command:

```
scm workspace add-components test-workspace -s test-stream "test1" "test2" -r url
```

I have tried building this as:

```
scm workspace add-components test-workspace -s test-stream "\test1\" \"test2\" -r url
```

Groovy method:

```
void addComponents(String repository, String name, String flowTarget, ArrayList components) {
    String compStr = components.toString().replace('[', '\"').replace(']', '\"').replace(', ', '\" \"')

    String cmd = """scm workspace add-components ${name} -s ${flowTarget} ${compStr} -r ${repository}"""
    println cmd

    def proc = cmd.execute()
    cmd.waitFor()

    getReturnMsg(proc)
}
```

Comment: Paste the groovy code You're trying to run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call `waitFor()` on `proc` not on `cmd`.